# Views Slideshow Contextual Filter, Show Images From Same Node

Tags: views

In a Content Type A I have added a image field with a value to add unlimited images.

Created nodes of Content Type A and adding multiple images to the field in all nodes of that content type.

Through Views Slideshow I have created a slideshow which is displaying all images added through that field.

Created a block display and configure that block to appear on nodes of the Content Type A.

Slide show is displaying all images added in different nodes of that content type.

I want views slideshow to display the images in context to the node it is appearing on. Means only display the images which are added on that particular node.

I think this could be achieved through contextual filters, but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a contextual filter for Content:Node:Nid, configure the 'When the filter value is NOT available' by selecting 'Provide default value, and under 'Type' select 'Content ID from URL'.

Save your view and you are done.

In your case, check for the nid or entity id associated with the attached (associated) images, and relate this to the node id in the URL. If your base table is node, the Content:node:nid will work. If your base table is files, you will need to use File Usage:Entity ID.